# Exclude blog directory from the public folder currently appear as 404 from URL

Tags: laravel, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to exclude my blog from my current routes. my-site-domain/blog is redirecting to 404.

The blog directory is in public folder
this is my .htacces file content placed outside public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    
    RewriteCond $1 !^(blog)
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond $1 !^(blog)
    RewriteRule ^ index.php
</IfModule>
```

it is not excluding blog directory as I have deployed wordpress in blog folder and want to have wp from that directory seprately i.e. my-domain.com/blog
Any suggestion would be really appriciated.
Thanks.

Comment: That configuration file you posted is confusing. It really actually does what you want, apart from the exception for that "blog" folder?

Comment: But it is not working for me. @arkascha